# How to complete a table of probabilities ?

Tags: probability, pattern-recognition

Im baffling myself as to why I cannot understand where it came from. Someone please explain to me like I'm five.

$$\begin{array}{c|c}
x & p(x) \\
\hline
0 & 0.73 \\
1 & ? \\
2 & 0.06 \\
3 & 0.04 \\
4 & 0.01 \\
\end{array}
$$

Can someone show me this pattern?
I know $p(1)=0.16$.

Comment: Presumably, you're defining the probability mass function of a discrete variable. The sum of the "$p(x)$"'s must be $1$. So if you're given all values save one, the unknown value is the sum of the known values subtracted from $1$. (Said another way, the $p(x)$ column must have sum $1$; so the missing value must be $.16$. This of course assumes your random variable takes only the values $0$, $1$, $2$, $3$, and $4$.)

Comment: Ah yes, thank you very much! @DavidMitra

Answer (score 0):

When the table of probabilities contains all values of $x$ attained by the random variable, the sum of $p$-values must be equal to $1$. Thus,
$$0.73 + p(1) + 0.06+0.04+0.01 = 1$$
from where $p(1)$ is found. (Après [David Mitra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/676425/how-to-complete-a-table-of-probabilities#comment1420767_676425))